# Elasticsearch 8.7.0 Installation issue: elasticsearch.bat cmd automatic closes without installation

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

After unzipping the elasticsearch-8.7.0-windows-x86_64.zip when I click on elasticsearch.bat of bin folder, It automatically closes without full installation. One solution I tried was  `xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true` added in /config/elasticsearch.yml
but also gave same error in log file. What should I do ? Please fix the issue of installation (Windows 10, RAM: 8 GB, Disc: 1 TB)

```
[2023-04-29T19:02:32,101][ERROR][o.e.b.Elasticsearch      ] [DESKTOP-RFII9P1] fatal exception while booting Elasticsearch
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: invalid configuration for xpack.security.transport.ssl - [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] is not set, but the following settings have been configured in elasticsearch.yml : [xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password,xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.validateServerConfiguration(SSLService.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSslConfigurations(SSLService.java:616) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:158) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:314) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$16(Node.java:722) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.lambda$flatMap$0(PluginsService.java:254) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:722) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:737) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:324) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch$2.<init>(Elasticsearch.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.initPhase3(Elasticsearch.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-8.7.0.jar:?]
```